# IBM DB2 9.7 VARCHAR([N]), does [N] stand for characters or bytes in UTF-8

Tags: db2, varchar

We use UTF-8 encoding in our IBM DB2 9.7 LUW database. Even though I did a lot of searching I could not find a definite answer to this question. If I define a table column to be VARCHAR(100), does it mean 100 characters or 100 bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [online IBM docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html), it's in bytes:

> **VARCHAR(integer), or CHARACTER VARYING(integer), or CHAR VARYING(integer)**
>
> For a varying-length character string of maximum length integer bytes, which may range from 1 to 32,672.

There's further information on [this page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008470.html) where you can see

```
SELECT CHARACTER_LENGTH (NAME, OCTETS) FROM T1 WHERE NAME = 'Jürgen'
```

gives you **7** because `ü` is encoded as `x'c3bc'`.